# application stops while receiving information from socket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, udp, snmp

SnmpV3 uses socket for the information I need to get. This is the information I should get, but (int inlen = socket.ReceiveFrom (inbuffer, SocketFlags.None, ref peer); the application stops at this sentence.how can i get this information?

```
 // We'll need a byte buffer to store incoming data
                byte[] inbuffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
                // End point details of the host we received packet(s) from
                EndPoint peer = (EndPoint)new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                // Create a IP/UDP socket
                Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,ProtocolType.Udp);
                // Bind the socket to the standard snmptrapd port = udp/162
                socket.Bind((EndPoint)new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 162));
                // Wait for a packet
                int inlen = socket.ReceiveFrom(inbuffer, SocketFlags.None, ref peer);
                // Make sure we received some data instead of an empty packet.
                if (inlen== 0 )
    {
                    Console.WriteLine("Received an invalid SNMP packet length 0 Bytes.");
                    socket.Close();
                    return;
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation. This is a blocking operation. That means execution of the thread is halted until the method returns.

> If no data is available for reading, the ReceiveFrom method will block
> until data is available. If you are in non-blocking mode, and there is
> no data available in the in the protocol stack buffer, the ReceiveFrom
> method will complete immediately and throw a SocketException. You can
> use the Available property to determine if data is available for
> reading. When Available is non-zero, retry the receive operation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receivefrom?view=netcore-3.1

To prevent this, you can run this operation on a dedicated background thread or use the socket class asynchronous methods.

`BeginReceiveFrom`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceivefrom?view=netcore-3.1

`ReceiveFromAsync`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receivefromasync?view=netcore-3.1